# What are the benefits of consolidating application code with vendor code?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gulp, minify

On my current project we have our gulp build process dropping our Angular application to two Javascript files; one for anything in the app (things we wrote), and one for vendor files (basically anything brought in; e.g. bower included).

Recently a request came from a more abstract influence on the project to consolidate the `app.js` and `vendor.js` (and CSS equivalents) into one file to reduce HTTP requests.

Now, I don't really have a lot of experience with gulp, but our original implementation was setup for the two files. My question is: is there actual benefit in consolidating the two, or is there a technical or practical reason for them to be separate? Perhaps this was the way the initial (probably Yeoman) scaffold laid them out, and if so, is there an architectural reason?

Thanks much in advance for any and all advice or experiences you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gulp will have no trouble compiling your vendor and app code into a single file. The benefit of this is it would reduce the number of requests your browser needs to make to a single script request.

However, two files are often used to make it more obvious where errors are coming from if they occur. It also means that compiling your app code is faster since it doesn't need to re-compile the vendor code whenever your app code changes. Typically, the vendor code is more stable so it shouldn't need frequent compiling (or even watching).

Additionally, with the advent of HTTP2 and its ability to do multiplex downloads, concatenating your code into one large file is a worse option. This is because even a small change results in the entire concatenated blob needing to be re-downloaded.